# Finding X in log equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation: 
$$\left(\frac{10}{e^x} - 1\right) = 2$$

$$\frac{10}{e^x} = 3$$
but from this point, I'm not too sure what to do.

I know I need to do the $\log$, and get $x$ by itself, but not too sure how to do this.

Comment: What equation if it don't have and equal?

Comment: You have an expression not an equation (at least from my mobile view).

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my equation. fixed it now.

Comment: Your equation is $$\frac{10}{e^x}-1=2$$ or $$\frac{10}{e^x-1}=2?$$

Comment: Smells like the former, based on what the OP did.

Comment: Meh, worked it out I think, I just multiply by like e^x and then do the log after I divide 3e^x  by 3.

I kinda messed up when I posted this, I actually though it was '-2' instead of '=2' which threw me off.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{10}{e^x}=3\implies 10=3e^x\implies \frac{10}{3}=e^x\implies \ln\left(\frac{10}{3}\right)=x$$